# How to COMPLETELY disable all channels shortcuts in Photoshop CC? (Mac OS)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac, shortcuts

Is there a way to override and disable the default shortcuts to select/toggle channels in photoshop? (the shortcuts are currently ⌘~, ⌘1, ⌘2, ⌘3).

I know you can set custom shortcuts for most things inside Photoshop but I couldn't find a way to change the channels shortcuts? The closest thing I've found is an option to use "legacy channels shortcuts" but thats not what I want since it still leaves a shortcut as an option. If not natively supported are there any hacks/scripts to disabling this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Direct answer, to a direct question: No, there is no way to override and disable the default shortcuts for toggling channels. They're hardcoded.

There were some grimaces about this when it was first done. As per usual, Adobe ignored them.

Answer (score 0):

This really annoyed me as well and took me hours to finally figure out. I've attached an image with the solution. You have to uncheck "Use Channels Legacy Shortcuts", but, in order for it to work, you have to restart Photoshop after and then, after you reopen PS, reassign the keys you want for Cmd/Ctrl+1/2/3/etc. [image]